# What is the difference to use CARET symbol in REGEXP_LIKE in oracle?

Tags: sql, regex, string, oracle, oracle11g

I am new to REGEX. So,I tried:

```
select * from ot.contacts where REGEXP_like(last_name,'^[A-C]');
```

Also,I tried:

```
select * from ot.contacts where REGEXP_like(last_name,'[A-C]');
```

both of them are giving me output where last_name starts with A,b,c and the no of records fetched is same.Can you tell me when I can see difference using this caret symbol?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this context, `^`  represents the beginning of the string.

- `'^[A-C]'` checks for A, B or C at the beginning of the string.
- `'[A-C]'` checks for A, B or C at the anywhere in the string.

Depending on your dataset, both expressions might, or might not produce the same output. Here is on example where the resultset would be different:

```
last_name         | ^[A-C]   | [A-C] 
----------------- | -------  | ----- 
Arthur            | match    | match
Bill              | match    | match
Jean-Christophe   | no match | match
```